# Azure CosmosDB Firewall for Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App hosting an API (ASP.NET MVC project) that interacts with a CosmosDB database and collections to get subscriptions and other information.
The CosmosDB database is accessed R/W by the Web App middle-ware uses through the nuget package "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" SDK v1.19.1.

I am trying to set up the CosmosDB IP Firewall through the Azure Portal. I allowed the Azure Portal to have access to the db and then I needed to also allow the web app (also hosted on Azure) to have access. To do this, I copied the Virtual IP Address  of the Web App from the Properties tab in the Azure Portal.
But this was not enough. I waited more than 10 minutes trying my web app but all the calls to the CosmosDB were rejected with error 404, which as the documentation states it is the proper behavior for SDK Calls (security reasons).
Then I added, all the Outbound IP Addresses stated at the same Properties Tab of the Web App. Waited for more than 20 mins and still 404 error.

What are the correct steps to achieve the requested task? 
For example in SQL On Azure, the IP Filtering allowed for an option, to allow access from any Azure App/ VM / Service. How can we achieve the equivalent in CosmosDB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try and add your webapp to the Access Control (IAM) of your CosmosDB in addition to the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Since Azure App Service is PaaS, and following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support#connections-from-azure-paas-service), please try adding the IP `0.0.0.0`.

On the Azure Portal, this can also be set by switching on `Allow access to Azure Services`.

[image: Firewall settings]